# How can I insert several rows at given position in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of data that had to be recorded every 30 seconds but some of it was recorded with a larger time step.

So I want to write a program with pandas to check the time steps and if they are larger than 30, insert specific number of NaN rows, then fill the NaN cells with interpolation. but I don't know how to write a code to do it for seveal times at different positions.

My data looks something like this (with many more rows and columns):

```
    T1  T2  time_step
0   15  30  30
1   19  40  90
2   18  30  30
3   16  50  90
4   16  70  30
...
```

and I want it to look like this before interpolation:

```
    T1  T2  time_step
0   15  30  30
1   NaN NaN 30
2   NaN NaN 30
3   19  40  90
4   18  30  30
5   NaN NaN 30
6   NaN NaN 30
7   16  50  90
8   16  70  30
...
```

I have found a code on this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-row-at-given-position-in-pandas-dataframe/
which inserts a row at a given position but my problem is I can not write a program to insert rows several times at different positions for a dataframe.

Is it even possible with pandas? Is there any other way to do it with python?

I want to write something like this but I don't know how to write a correct code for it:

```
### The function close to what I found in the link above:

def Insert_row(row_number, df, m, row_value):
    start_upper = 0
    end_upper = row_number

    start_lower = row_number
    end_lower = df.shape[0]

    upper_half = [*range(start_upper, end_upper, 1)]
    lower_half = [*range(start_lower, end_lower, 1)]

    lower_half = [x.__add__(m) for x in lower_half]

    index_ = upper_half + lower_half

    df.index = index_
    
    for i in range(row_number, row_number+m):
        df.loc[i] = row_value

    df = df.sort_index()

    return df

**### The main problem:
for j in range(dm.shape[0]):
    if dm['time_step'][j] != 30:
        row_number = j
        m = dm['time_step'][j]/ 30 - 1
        row_value = [np.Nan, np.NaN, 30]
        dm_new = Insert_row(row_number, dm, m, row_value)**

dm_new = dm_new.interpolate()
```

(I know the range is wrong and it is wrong to modify what I'm iterating over but I don't know how to write it correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a lot of ways to solve this. If I understand correctly, you want to insert two rows everytime when `time_step` is 90. If you have more general cases as well, we would need to modify the solution a bit.

This is a very imperative requirement. For this case, I would work very directly with the indices of the data and therefore use the underlying numpy array instead of pandas.

```
In [54]: a = df.copy().values

In [55]: a
Out[55]: 
array([[15, 30, 30],
       [19, 40, 90],
       [18, 30, 30],
       [16, 50, 90],
       [16, 70, 30]])

In [56]: index = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(a[:,2] > 30))

In [57]: index
Out[57]: array([1, 3])

In [58]: np.insert(a.astype(np.float64), obj=np.repeat(index, 2), values=np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 30]), axis=0)
Out[58]: 
array([[15., 30., 30.],
       [nan, nan, 30.],
       [nan, nan, 30.],
       [19., 40., 90.],
       [18., 30., 30.],
       [nan, nan, 30.],
       [nan, nan, 30.],
       [16., 50., 90.],
       [16., 70., 30.]])
```

Then you can create a new DataFrame with these values.

```
In [74]: pd.DataFrame(np.insert(a.astype(np.float64), obj=np.repeat(index, 2), values=np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 30]), axis=0), columns=df.columns)
Out[74]: 
     T1    T2  time_step
0  15.0  30.0       30.0
1   NaN   NaN       30.0
2   NaN   NaN       30.0
3  19.0  40.0       90.0
4  18.0  30.0       30.0
5   NaN   NaN       30.0
6   NaN   NaN       30.0
7  16.0  50.0       90.0
8  16.0  70.0       30.0
```

The `index` are the row numbers where your second column (`'time_step'`) is larger than `30`. You could still do this with pandas. However to insert rows *in the middle* of your DataFrame, there simply is no API function. Therefore we go to numpy. We need to convert to float, because np.nan is not a valid integer. Repeating the `index` twice, makes it insert the row twice. And finally the row to insert is `np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 30])` and `axis=0` means we insert rows.